# selenium: test "disable on submit" behavior

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

We're using Selenium WebDriver to test a form that has a double-post prevention behavior. There's some simple javascript that disables the button upon click, so that users won't accidentally post the same thing twice.

How do we test this?

The issues is that the `button.click()` blocks until the next page has loaded, at which point we certainly can't assert anything about the button on the previous page. Even if we were to somehow get the `.click()` to be non-blocking, there's an inherent race condition; if the browser/javascript is much faster than the test system, it will be able to unload the page before the test can assert anything about the button.

Bonus points for solutions without javascript injection hacks.

Comment: button.click() really blocks? My observations have concluded otherwise.

Comment: @AshwinPrabhu It blocks in the best way WebDriver can guess. If there's an async request for a new page, it won't. If you click on a link, it definitely should block.

Comment: @AshwinPrabhu: Are you using RC or WebDriver? If you use the trivial html form with just a button, you should see that you don't regain control in your test until after the page refresh. I've found that if javascript is doing a `event.preventDefault()`, then selenium will return earlier, but that's not the normal case.

Comment: @bukzor Talking about webdriver ofcourse. My observation was that JavascriptExecutor interface blocks for the duration of the script execution, but click and other actions need not necessarily block. IEDriver I think tries its best to make API's blocking, but can't say that about all implementations. My observation is old and may not apply at present.

Comment: @Slanec So clicking on link that loads a page makes button.click() blocking? Hmmm... never looked at this closely. This means that API behavior is not consistent?

Comment: @AshwinPrabhu On the contrary, this is explicitly said in [the documentation](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#click%28%29).

Comment: @Slanec Links to documentation ++

Comment: @Slanec Thanks for the link. I think there was a disconnect. I was talking about any scripts that are invoked in response to click event. WebDriver does not block even if the browser gets into busy state in response to click event processing. Thanks for clearing the discussion on page load on click - I wasn't aware of this behavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the assumption that <kbd>Esc</kbd> cancels page loading in every browser and OS, this should work:

```java
WebElement input = driver.findElement(By.tagName("input")); 
input.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER, Keys.ESCAPE);
Assert.assertFalse(input.isEnabled());
```

It sends <kbd>Enter</kbd> and <kbd>Esc</kbd> to the button in rapid succession, so that the JavaScript is fired, but the page load has no chance of kicking in. The only problem I can see is that you won't be able to get to the next page with this test unless you refresh and send a new form. But we should only test one feature at a time anyway, so you're fine ;-).

---

**EDIT** (to address your comment)

Actually, yes! You can try to se send a click and the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key at the same time via [The Advanced User Interactions API](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#advanceduserinteractions) ([JavaDocs](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/index.html?org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html)). *You can also achieve a nonblocking click this way.*

Anyway, this approach still sends two requests which isn't the fastest imaginable thing to do, but it (sometimes barely) passes my test, so you might give it a try:

```java
WebElement input = driver.findElement(By.tagName("input"));
new Actions(driver)
        .click(input)
        .sendKeys(input, Keys.ESCAPE)
        .perform();
```

---

Test environment: IE8 and FF18 with a locally stored file and Selenium 2.29.1; Win XP SP3.
The test file looks like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="http://google.com/">
        <input type="button" value="Hello." onclick="this.disabled='true';" />
    </a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well that's a start! It's actually more reasonable than it sounded at first. I was surprised that you can activate `onclick` with the keyboard, but it makes sense. Would you expect that this would ever give different results than `.click`, in the general case? Is there no way to send a click+escape?

Comment: @bukzor In general, the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key is equivalent to a left-click when opening links and operating with buttons. When trying to check a checkbox, you should use a <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> instead. There is no w3c standard for this (that I have found), but you [can](http://goo.gl/Su8c1) [see](http://goo.gl/eKLRH) [everyone conforms to these](http://goo.gl/ggHGI) so that you could navigate in browser without a mouse. Also, there always could be someone actively listening for key presses and preventing them to happen.

Comment: @bukzor The Click+Escape solution has been edited into the answer, look there.

Comment: Thanks! Accepted. I'm curious; to do a nonblocking click, would I just use an actionchain with only the click defined?

Comment: @bukzor Yep. Given that, both the solutions I proposed (and the one you're thinking about with just the `click()`) don't theoretically need the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key, because they don't block. Good luck with your tests!

Comment: The <esc> certainly helps solve the raciness issue, as the problem was originally posed. TYVM.